# SVN command that returns whether a user has a valid login for a repository

Tags: login, svn

I'm trying to find out an SVN command that would return some kind of true / false value depending on whether the user running it has access to a given repository.

I'm building a tool for automated deployment and, part of the process is checking out the code from the SVN repository. I'd like to find out if the user running the tool already has a valid login. If there's no valid login, just show a message and exit the tool (handling the SVN login internally is not an option at the moment).

Plan B would be parsing the file in svn.simple looking for the repo URL, but thought about asking first.

Thanks,

Juan

Answer (score 1):

Calling `svn` with the `--non-interactive` command-line option disables any prompts for credentials. By checking svn's exit code, you would be able to determine whether the checkout was succesful. If not, you could let your script die with an error message.

Of course, a non-zero exit code for svn doesn't mean it's necessarily an authentication problem, but it's *something*...

Comment: Not a bad attempt, but would like to get something "official" : )